# From a gitlab docker runner, How to inject a command into the stdin of another running docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

From a gitlab docker runner, I would like to inject a command into the stdin of another docker running on the same docker daemon.  The docker daemon socket is mounted into the gitlab runner and works correctly.

That targeted docker is composed with those options set:

```
tty: true
stdin_open: true
```

I've attempt this solution (found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/885765/how-to-send-text-to-stdin-of-docker-container):

```bash
echo "my_command" | socat -v EXEC:"docker attach targeted_docker",pty STDIN
```

It works well on a common environment (laptop with debian), but it does not work within the gitlab-ci.  As I understand, this is because no TTY exists while running in the gilab runner.

Does anyone have a workaround for this ?